# Xamarin iOS custom map design

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Is it possible to have an map view in xamarin ios with an image view overlaying it, so you cannot see the actual map, but on top of the image view are Annotations and custom pins, if it is possible can someone help me or provide references?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/map_view/add_an_overlay_to_a_map/